# Simultaneous Equations Finding the Intersection of a Cubic and a Quadratic

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations, quadratics, cubics

My functions are

y = -0.65(x -8.165)^2 + 1.5(x -8.165) + 6.872

y = 0.08(x-11)^3 -2.2(x-11) + 5.9

By using simultaneous equations and equating the functions to one another I've simplified it to the point where:

0.08x^3 - 1.99x^2 + 14.7255x - 27.608 = 0

This had me stuck for a while but when I looked it up online I found I could use the Newton - Raphson Method to solve it.

I got the intercepts:
x = 2.85281 , x = 10.98682 , x = 11.03536

And although this helped me greatly, for the assignment I'm doing I won't be marked on using that method as we haven't been taught it and it's not on the criteria.

I'm just wondering if there is another method I can use that would get the same results.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but note you can solve for the roots of a [cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) analytically. This would actually generally give you answers which are more accurate than you can reasonably get numerically, although this is not much of an issue if your initial equation coefficients may not be completely accurate, or if just a few decimal places of accuracy is sufficient.

Comment: How would I go about incorporating this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "incorporating this". The steps to use are given in the Wikipedia article. If you haven't yet, please read the article and try to apply the details it provides to your specific cubic equation.

Answer (score 1):

You know that you have three real roots.

Using whole numbers, your cubic equation write
$$\frac{2 }{25}x^3-\frac{199 }{100}x^2+\frac{29451}{2000}x-\frac{22136643}{800000}=0$$

Use the trigonometric method as described in the Wikipedia page and get the nice
$$x_k=\frac{199}{24}+\frac{19}{12} \sqrt{\frac{59}{5}} \cos \left(\frac{2 k\pi  }{3}-\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(-\frac{69497939}{4046810 \sqrt{295}}\right)\right)$$ with $k=0,1,2$.